# I Need to disable prevButton when the page loads React

Tags: reactjs

I want to disabled the prev button when count = 0; which is by default when count is assigned
I tried to use disabled attr and then remove it using the if condition but is not being disabled by default.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
// let count = 0;
function Slides({slides}) {

    let [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    // let [isDisabled, setisDisabled] = useState(false);
    
    

    if(count >= (slides.length - 1)){
        $('.nextButton').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('.nextButton').attr("disabled", false);
    }

    if(count <= 0){
        $('.prevButton').attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $('.prevButton').attr("disabled", false);
    }

    if(count < 1){
        $('.prevButton').attr("disabled", true);
    }

   

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="navigation" className="text-center">
                <button data-testid="button-restart" onClick={() => setCount(count = 0)} className="small outlined">Restart</button>
                <button data-testid="button-prev"  onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)} className="small prevButton">Prev</button>
                <button data-testid="button-next"   onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}  className="small nextButton">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div id="slide" className="card text-center">
                <h1 data-testid="title">{slides[count].title}</h1>
                <p data-testid="text">{slides[count].text}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Slides;
```

Comment: jQuery and React should not be needed together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You no need to use jquery here. Create one more state for tracking disabled state and use that in the template for setting the attribute.

`disabled={isDisabled}`

Move all the condition to `useEffect` and give `count` as a dependency.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

// let count = 0;
function Slides({slides}) {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [isDisabled, setisDisabled] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(count >= (slides.length - 1)){
            setisDisabled(true);
        } else {
            setisDisabled(false);
        }

        if(count <= 0){
            setisDisabled(true);
        } else {
            setisDisabled(false);
        }
    
        if(count < 1){
            setisDisabled(true);
        }

    }, [count]);

    return (
        <div>
            <div id="navigation" className="text-center">
                <button data-testid="button-restart" onClick={() => setCount(0)} className="small outlined">Restart</button>
                <button data-testid="button-prev"  onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)} className="small prevButton" disabled={isDisabled}>Prev</button>
                <button data-testid="button-next"   onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}  className="small nextButton">Next</button>
            </div>
            {<div id="slide" className="card text-center">
                <h1 data-testid="title">{slides[count].title}</h1>
                <p data-testid="text">{slides[count].text}</p>
            </div>}
        </div>
    );

}

export default Slides;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, UKS! It worked...! Thanks again!

Comment: Ok but getting this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."